# How do I select only the last generated input field

Tags: jquery, input, append, dynamically-generated

I,m generating new input fields after klicking a Button.

I want to select and add a keypress/input event only to the LAST generated input field.

Here is my try:

```
$(document.body).on("input", $(".input-field").last(), function (e) {
  //some logic
});
```

also tried thied with :last-child - didn't work

But all inputs are listening to my keypress or input event.

**How do I select only the last *generated* input field?**

Comment: "LAST generated input field" is always your last input in the dom structure?

Comment: Yes, its always the last one. And more input fields will be generated after typing, so that they will be the last inut fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the [`:last` selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```js
$(document.body).on("input", ".input-field:last", function (e) {
   $(this).next('div').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
<!-- only this one gets the event handler -->
<input class="input-field" type="text"><div></div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!! Now I see what i did wrong in my code. I got one further question. How do i stop the listening after typing?
Were do i install something like ".off()" or ".one()"

If you are interrested: This question was a small part of a much more difficult question [Add key eventlistener to last generated input field and stop it after typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631069/add-key-eventlistener-to-last-generated-input-field-and-stop-it-after-typinghel) ;-)

Comment: @user3465835 - do you mean when that field loses focus? Ive posted an answer on your linked question - hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i saw it - thanks again! You made my day!
because :last did not work in my try, i was not able to work with (this) - i trapped myself by not getting ":last" to work